# Make a bubble chart in ionic framework (with highcharts-ng?)

Tags: charts, ionic-framework, bubble-chart, highcharts-ng

I am programming an app using [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) and I need to show charts.
For one of them I wanted to try a **bubble chart**, but I can't seem to find how to do it using [highcharts-ng](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng). I know the original library Highcharts has the bubble chart but I can't seem to find it in highcharts-ng. Is it supported? If yes how can I do it?

Designers want us to achieve something that looks like this:

[image: Chart example]

Is there any way to customize highcharts-ng to do this? Or anything else I could use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please my code given below  to implement bubble chart using ng-highchart

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["highcharts-ng"]);

myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {



    $scope.chartConfig = {
        options: {
            chart: {
                type: 'scatter',
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: 100,
                y: 70,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF',
                borderWidth: 1

            },
            plotOptions: {
                scatter: {
                    marker: {
                        radius: 5,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true,
                                lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            marker: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                        pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                enabled: true,
                text: 'Height (cm)'
            },
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            showLastLabel: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Weight (kg)'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Female',
            color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
            data: [
                [161.2, 51.6],
                [167.5, 59.0],
                [159.5, 49.2],
                [157.0, 63.0],
                [155.8, 53.6],
                [170.0, 59.0],
                [159.1, 47.6],
                [166.0, 69.8],
                [176.2, 66.8],
                [160.2, 75.2],
                [172.5, 55.2],
                [170.9, 54.2],
                [172.9, 62.5],
                [153.4, 42.0],
                [160.0, 50.0],
                [147.2, 49.8],
                [168.2, 49.2],
                [175.0, 73.2],
                [157.0, 47.8],
                [167.6, 68.8],
                [159.5, 50.6],
                [175.0, 82.5],
                [166.8, 57.2],
                [176.5, 87.8],
                [170.2, 72.8],
                [174.0, 54.5],
                [173.0, 59.8],
                [179.9, 67.3],
                [170.5, 67.8],
                [160.0, 47.0],
                [154.4, 46.2],
                [162.0, 55.0],
                [176.5, 83.0],
                [160.0, 54.4],
                [152.0, 45.8],
                [162.1, 53.6],
                [170.0, 73.2],
                [160.2, 52.1],
                [161.3, 67.9],
                [166.4, 56.6],
                [168.9, 62.3],
                [163.8, 58.5],
                [167.6, 54.5],
                [160.0, 50.2],
                [161.3, 60.3],
                [167.6, 58.3],
                [165.1, 56.2],
                [160.0, 50.2],
                [170.0, 72.9],
                [157.5, 59.8],
                [167.6, 61.0],
                [160.7, 69.1],
                [163.2, 55.9],
                [152.4, 46.5],
                [157.5, 54.3],
                [168.3, 54.8],
                [180.3, 60.7],
                [165.5, 60.0],
                [165.0, 62.0],
                [164.5, 60.3],
                [156.0, 52.7],
                [160.0, 74.3],
                [163.0, 62.0],
                [165.7, 73.1],
                [161.0, 80.0],
                [162.0, 54.7],
                [166.0, 53.2],
                [174.0, 75.7],
                [172.7, 61.1],
                [167.6, 55.7],
                [151.1, 48.7],
                [164.5, 52.3],
                [163.5, 50.0],
                [152.0, 59.3],
                [169.0, 62.5],
                [164.0, 55.7],
                [161.2, 54.8],
                [155.0, 45.9],
                [170.0, 70.6],
                [176.2, 67.2],
                [170.0, 69.4],
                [162.5, 58.2],
                [170.3, 64.8],
                [164.1, 71.6],
                [169.5, 52.8],
                [163.2, 59.8],
                [154.5, 49.0],
                [159.8, 50.0],
                [173.2, 69.2],
                [170.0, 55.9],
                [161.4, 63.4],
                [169.0, 58.2],
                [166.2, 58.6],
                [159.4, 45.7],
                [162.5, 52.2],
                [159.0, 48.6],
                [162.8, 57.8],
                [159.0, 55.6],
                [179.8, 66.8],
                [162.9, 59.4],
                [161.0, 53.6],
                [151.1, 73.2],
                [168.2, 53.4],
                [168.9, 69.0],
                [173.2, 58.4],
                [171.8, 56.2],
                [178.0, 70.6],
                [164.3, 59.8],
                [163.0, 72.0],
                [168.5, 65.2],
                [166.8, 56.6],
                [172.7, 105.2],
                [163.5, 51.8],
                [169.4, 63.4],
                [167.8, 59.0],
                [159.5, 47.6],
                [167.6, 63.0],
                [161.2, 55.2],
                [160.0, 45.0],
                [163.2, 54.0],
                [162.2, 50.2],
                [161.3, 60.2],
                [149.5, 44.8],
                [157.5, 58.8],
                [163.2, 56.4],
                [172.7, 62.0],
                [155.0, 49.2],
                [156.5, 67.2],
                [164.0, 53.8],
                [160.9, 54.4],
                [162.8, 58.0],
                [167.0, 59.8],
                [160.0, 54.8],
                [160.0, 43.2],
                [168.9, 60.5],
                [158.2, 46.4],
                [156.0, 64.4],
                [160.0, 48.8],
                [167.1, 62.2],
                [158.0, 55.5],
                [167.6, 57.8],
                [156.0, 54.6],
                [162.1, 59.2],
                [173.4, 52.7],
                [159.8, 53.2],
                [170.5, 64.5],
                [159.2, 51.8],
                [157.5, 56.0],
                [161.3, 63.6],
                [162.6, 63.2],
                [160.0, 59.5],
                [168.9, 56.8],
                [165.1, 64.1],
                [162.6, 50.0],
                [165.1, 72.3],
                [166.4, 55.0],
                [160.0, 55.9],
                [152.4, 60.4],
                [170.2, 69.1],
                [162.6, 84.5],
                [170.2, 55.9],
                [158.8, 55.5],
                [172.7, 69.5],
                [167.6, 76.4],
                [162.6, 61.4],
                [167.6, 65.9],
                [156.2, 58.6],
                [175.2, 66.8],
                [172.1, 56.6],
                [162.6, 58.6],
                [160.0, 55.9],
                [165.1, 59.1],
                [182.9, 81.8],
                [166.4, 70.7],
                [165.1, 56.8],
                [177.8, 60.0],
                [165.1, 58.2],
                [175.3, 72.7],
                [154.9, 54.1],
                [158.8, 49.1],
                [172.7, 75.9],
                [168.9, 55.0],
                [161.3, 57.3],
                [167.6, 55.0],
                [165.1, 65.5],
                [175.3, 65.5],
                [157.5, 48.6],
                [163.8, 58.6],
                [167.6, 63.6],
                [165.1, 55.2],
                [165.1, 62.7],
                [168.9, 56.6],
                [162.6, 53.9],
                [164.5, 63.2],
                [176.5, 73.6],
                [168.9, 62.0],
                [175.3, 63.6],
                [159.4, 53.2],
                [160.0, 53.4],
                [170.2, 55.0],
                [162.6, 70.5],
                [167.6, 54.5],
                [162.6, 54.5],
                [160.7, 55.9],
                [160.0, 59.0],
                [157.5, 63.6],
                [162.6, 54.5],
                [152.4, 47.3],
                [170.2, 67.7],
                [165.1, 80.9],
                [172.7, 70.5],
                [165.1, 60.9],
                [170.2, 63.6],
                [170.2, 54.5],
                [170.2, 59.1],
                [161.3, 70.5],
                [167.6, 52.7],
                [167.6, 62.7],
                [165.1, 86.3],
                [162.6, 66.4],
                [152.4, 67.3],
                [168.9, 63.0],
                [170.2, 73.6],
                [175.2, 62.3],
                [175.2, 57.7],
                [160.0, 55.4],
                [165.1, 104.1],
                [174.0, 55.5],
                [170.2, 77.3],
                [160.0, 80.5],
                [167.6, 64.5],
                [167.6, 72.3],
                [167.6, 61.4],
                [154.9, 58.2],
                [162.6, 81.8],
                [175.3, 63.6],
                [171.4, 53.4],
                [157.5, 54.5],
                [165.1, 53.6],
                [160.0, 60.0],
                [174.0, 73.6],
                [162.6, 61.4],
                [174.0, 55.5],
                [162.6, 63.6],
                [161.3, 60.9],
                [156.2, 60.0],
                [149.9, 46.8],
                [169.5, 57.3],
                [160.0, 64.1],
                [175.3, 63.6],
                [169.5, 67.3],
                [160.0, 75.5],
                [172.7, 68.2],
                [162.6, 61.4],
                [157.5, 76.8],
                [176.5, 71.8],
                [164.4, 55.5],
                [160.7, 48.6],
                [174.0, 66.4],
                [163.8, 67.3]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Male',
            color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
            data: [
                [174.0, 65.6],
                [175.3, 71.8],
                [193.5, 80.7],
                [186.5, 72.6],
                [187.2, 78.8],
                [181.5, 74.8],
                [184.0, 86.4],
                [184.5, 78.4],
                [175.0, 62.0],
                [184.0, 81.6],
                [180.0, 76.6],
                [177.8, 83.6],
                [192.0, 90.0],
                [176.0, 74.6],
                [174.0, 71.0],
                [184.0, 79.6],
                [192.7, 93.8],
                [171.5, 70.0],
                [173.0, 72.4],
                [176.0, 85.9],
                [176.0, 78.8],
                [180.5, 77.8],
                [172.7, 66.2],
                [176.0, 86.4],
                [173.5, 81.8],
                [178.0, 89.6],
                [180.3, 82.8],
                [180.3, 76.4],
                [164.5, 63.2],
                [173.0, 60.9],
                [183.5, 74.8],
                [175.5, 70.0],
                [188.0, 72.4],
                [189.2, 84.1],
                [172.8, 69.1],
                [170.0, 59.5],
                [182.0, 67.2],
                [170.0, 61.3],
                [177.8, 68.6],
                [184.2, 80.1],
                [186.7, 87.8],
                [171.4, 84.7],
                [172.7, 73.4],
                [175.3, 72.1],
                [180.3, 82.6],
                [182.9, 88.7],
                [188.0, 84.1],
                [177.2, 94.1],
                [172.1, 74.9],
                [167.0, 59.1],
                [169.5, 75.6],
                [174.0, 86.2],
                [172.7, 75.3],
                [182.2, 87.1],
                [164.1, 55.2],
                [163.0, 57.0],
                [171.5, 61.4],
                [184.2, 76.8],
                [174.0, 86.8],
                [174.0, 72.2],
                [177.0, 71.6],
                [186.0, 84.8],
                [167.0, 68.2],
                [171.8, 66.1],
                [182.0, 72.0],
                [167.0, 64.6],
                [177.8, 74.8],
                [164.5, 70.0],
                [192.0, 101.6],
                [175.5, 63.2],
                [171.2, 79.1],
                [181.6, 78.9],
                [167.4, 67.7],
                [181.1, 66.0],
                [177.0, 68.2],
                [174.5, 63.9],
                [177.5, 72.0],
                [170.5, 56.8],
                [182.4, 74.5],
                [197.1, 90.9],
                [180.1, 93.0],
                [175.5, 80.9],
                [180.6, 72.7],
                [184.4, 68.0],
                [175.5, 70.9],
                [180.6, 72.5],
                [177.0, 72.5],
                [177.1, 83.4],
                [181.6, 75.5],
                [176.5, 73.0],
                [175.0, 70.2],
                [174.0, 73.4],
                [165.1, 70.5],
                [177.0, 68.9],
                [192.0, 102.3],
                [176.5, 68.4],
                [169.4, 65.9],
                [182.1, 75.7],
                [179.8, 84.5],
                [175.3, 87.7],
                [184.9, 86.4],
                [177.3, 73.2],
                [167.4, 53.9],
                [178.1, 72.0],
                [168.9, 55.5],
                [157.2, 58.4],
                [180.3, 83.2],
                [170.2, 72.7],
                [177.8, 64.1],
                [172.7, 72.3],
                [165.1, 65.0],
                [186.7, 86.4],
                [165.1, 65.0],
                [174.0, 88.6],
                [175.3, 84.1],
                [185.4, 66.8],
                [177.8, 75.5],
                [180.3, 93.2],
                [180.3, 82.7],
                [177.8, 58.0],
                [177.8, 79.5],
                [177.8, 78.6],
                [177.8, 71.8],
                [177.8, 116.4],
                [163.8, 72.2],
                [188.0, 83.6],
                [198.1, 85.5],
                [175.3, 90.9],
                [166.4, 85.9],
                [190.5, 89.1],
                [166.4, 75.0],
                [177.8, 77.7],
                [179.7, 86.4],
                [172.7, 90.9],
                [190.5, 73.6],
                [185.4, 76.4],
                [168.9, 69.1],
                [167.6, 84.5],
                [175.3, 64.5],
                [170.2, 69.1],
                [190.5, 108.6],
                [177.8, 86.4],
                [190.5, 80.9],
                [177.8, 87.7],
                [184.2, 94.5],
                [176.5, 80.2],
                [177.8, 72.0],
                [180.3, 71.4],
                [171.4, 72.7],
                [172.7, 84.1],
                [172.7, 76.8],
                [177.8, 63.6],
                [177.8, 80.9],
                [182.9, 80.9],
                [170.2, 85.5],
                [167.6, 68.6],
                [175.3, 67.7],
                [165.1, 66.4],
                [185.4, 102.3],
                [181.6, 70.5],
                [172.7, 95.9],
                [190.5, 84.1],
                [179.1, 87.3],
                [175.3, 71.8],
                [170.2, 65.9],
                [193.0, 95.9],
                [171.4, 91.4],
                [177.8, 81.8],
                [177.8, 96.8],
                [167.6, 69.1],
                [167.6, 82.7],
                [180.3, 75.5],
                [182.9, 79.5],
                [176.5, 73.6],
                [186.7, 91.8],
                [188.0, 84.1],
                [188.0, 85.9],
                [177.8, 81.8],
                [174.0, 82.5],
                [177.8, 80.5],
                [171.4, 70.0],
                [185.4, 81.8],
                [185.4, 84.1],
                [188.0, 90.5],
                [188.0, 91.4],
                [182.9, 89.1],
                [176.5, 85.0],
                [175.3, 69.1],
                [175.3, 73.6],
                [188.0, 80.5],
                [188.0, 82.7],
                [175.3, 86.4],
                [170.5, 67.7],
                [179.1, 92.7],
                [177.8, 93.6],
                [175.3, 70.9],
                [182.9, 75.0],
                [170.8, 93.2],
                [188.0, 93.2],
                [180.3, 77.7],
                [177.8, 61.4],
                [185.4, 94.1],
                [168.9, 75.0],
                [185.4, 83.6],
                [180.3, 85.5],
                [174.0, 73.9],
                [167.6, 66.8],
                [182.9, 87.3],
                [160.0, 72.3],
                [180.3, 88.6],
                [167.6, 75.5],
                [186.7, 101.4],
                [175.3, 91.1],
                [175.3, 67.3],
                [175.9, 77.7],
                [175.3, 81.8],
                [179.1, 75.5],
                [181.6, 84.5],
                [177.8, 76.6],
                [182.9, 85.0],
                [177.8, 102.5],
                [184.2, 77.3],
                [179.1, 71.8],
                [176.5, 87.9],
                [188.0, 94.3],
                [174.0, 70.9],
                [167.6, 64.5],
                [170.2, 77.3],
                [167.6, 72.3],
                [188.0, 87.3],
                [174.0, 80.0],
                [176.5, 82.3],
                [180.3, 73.6],
                [167.6, 74.1],
                [188.0, 85.9],
                [180.3, 73.2],
                [167.6, 76.3],
                [183.0, 65.9],
                [183.0, 90.9],
                [179.1, 89.1],
                [170.2, 62.3],
                [177.8, 82.7],
                [179.1, 79.1],
                [190.5, 98.2],
                [177.8, 84.1],
                [180.3, 83.2],
                [180.3, 83.2]
            ]



        }],
        title: {
            text: 'Height Versus Weight of 507 Individuals by Gender'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Heinz  2003'
        },
        loading: false
    }

});
```

```html
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="myctrl">
        <div class="row">
            <highchart id="chart1" config="chartConfig" class="span10"></highchart>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```